# xdot alternative / broken error print / sbt-dependency-graph

Tags: sbt, graphviz, dot

I'm trying to render a .dot output generated by the [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin. For some reason, xdot fails to open the file with something that looks like a bug in the Python code:

```
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style stroke-dasharray: 5 - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style 5 - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style stroke-dasharray: 5 - ignoring
[...]
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style 5 - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style stroke-dasharray: 5 - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style 5 - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style stroke-dasharray: 5 - ignoring
Warning: gvrender_set_style: unsupported style 5 - ignoring
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot.py", line 2060, in on_open
    self.open_file(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot.py", line 2029, in open_file
    self.set_dotcode(fp.read(), filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot.py", line 2011, in set_dotcode
    if self.widget.set_dotcode(dotcode, filename):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot.py", line 1546, in set_dotcode
    self.set_xdotcode(xdotcode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot.py", line 1565, in set_xdotcode
    self.graph = parser.parse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot.py", line 1236, in parse
    DotParser.parse(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot.py", line 1036, in parse
    self.parse_graph()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot.py", line 1045, in parse_graph
    self.parse_stmt()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot.py", line 1091, in parse_stmt
    self.handle_node(id, attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot.py", line 1211, in handle_node
    shapes.extend(parser.parse())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot.py", line 658, in parse
    self.handle_font_characteristics(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot.py", line 723, in handle_font_characteristics
    sys.stderr.write("warning: font characteristics not supported yet\n" % op)
NameError: global name 'op' is not defined
```

The .dot file does not contain *any* font specifications whatsoever. Since I use xdot a lot, I can only imagine the bug is caused by HTML style highlight, like

```
[label=<at.iem.sysson<BR/><B>sysson_2.11</B><BR/>1.8.0-SNAPSHOT> style=""]
```

Is there a **way to remove the label styling in sbt-dependency-graph**, or is there **an alternative .dot viewer for Linux** that is not written in a buggy Python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can simply run `dot` to convert to pdf and bypass Python.

```
dot -T pdf target/dependencies-compile.dot >out.pdf
evince out.pdf
```